# Cloning and drawing Objects in monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

How do I clone an object then pick a random position, then draw it.

This is the code I have for the object:

```
public class Trash : ICloneable
    {
        private Texture2D _texture;

        private float _rotation;

        public Vector2 Position;

        
        public Vector2 Origin;

        
        public float RotationVelocity = 3f;

       
        public float LinearVelocity = 4f;

        public Trash(Texture2D texture)
        {
            _texture = texture;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
         // Do epic stuff here            

        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, Position, null, Color.White, _rotation, Origin, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        }
        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
```

And this is code I have in Game1.cs so far:

```
public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        private SeaJam.Objects.Trash Trash;
        

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Prototype");

            Trash = new Objects.Trash(texture)
            {
                Position = new Vector2(100, 100),
                Origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height - 25),
            };
        }
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            Trash.Update();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            Trash.Draw(spriteBatch);

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
        private void AddTrash()
        {
            var rnd = new System.Random();
            var NewTrash = Trash.Clone();

            
        }
```

The problem is Whenever I'd try to give a random position for the clone in the AddTrash() Method, I'd only get errors, such as "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Position' and no accessible extension method 'Position' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your constructor:

```
public Trash(Texture2D texture)
{
    _texture = texture;
}
```

Needs to be extended with the desired changeable parameters. In your case, it needs to add `Position` and `Origin` as parameter, and then apply it as a value.

Like this:

```
public Trash(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Vector2 origin)
{
    _texture = texture;
    Position = position;
    Origin = origin;
}
```

And change the way you call it in the game1.cs as well, they need to work similair like `texture`:

```
var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Prototype");
var position = new Vector2(100, 100),
var origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height - 25),

Trash = new Objects.Trash(texture, position, origin);
```

And as a tip: keep consistency in your field names, mixing in underscore and lowercase in one field, and uppercase in an other field will get confusing to understand. especially when the parameters needs a name different from the fields as well. I prefer to keep them all with the first letter uppercase.